# Как получить средний столбец из текстового файла?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Есть файл:

```
Flags: X - disabled, R - radius, D - dynamic, B - blocked
 #   ADDRESS                                                                     MAC-ADDRESS       HOST-NAME                                   SERVER                                   RATE-LIMIT                                   STATUS
 0 D 192.168.5.230                                                               AA:BB:CC:DD:EE:FF android-a42cc69f72fe421a                    dhcp1                                                                                 bound
 1 D 192.168.5.245                                                               AA:BB:CC:DD:EE:FF Galaxy-Tab-A-80-2019                        dhcp1                                                                                 bound
 2 D 192.168.5.229                                                               AA:BB:CC:DD:EE:FF Redmi4-Redmi1111                            dhcp1                                                                                 bound
 3 D 192.168.5.195                                                               AA:BB:CC:DD:EE:FF RedmiNote8T-Redmi                           dhcp1                                                                                 bound
```

Хочу оттуда получить мак-адрес и хостнейм. С помощью моего варианта, у меня получается только получить айпишник

```
found = False
items = []
file = open('C:/Users/sk/Desktop/Python3/12/16/3.txt', 'r')
for line in file:
    line = line.strip()

    mac = line.split('                                                               ') [0]
    hostname = line.split(' ') [0]
    items.append( {'ip': hostname, 'mac': mac} )

for item in items:
    with open('C:/Users/sk/Desktop/Python3/12/16/result.txt', 'a') as file1:
        file1.write(format(item['ip'] + '\n'))
        print(format(item['mac']) + format(item['ip']))
```

Мой вывод:

```
Flags: X - disabled, R - radius, D - dynamic, B - blockedFlags:
#   ADDRESS#
0 D 192.168.5.2300
1 D 192.168.5.2451
2 D 192.168.5.2292
3 D 192.168.5.1953
4 D 192.168.5.2214
5 D 192.168.5.1135
6 D 192.168.5.2266
7 D 192.168.5.1617
8 D 192.168.5.118
9 D 192.168.5.669
10 D 192.168.5.18010
11 D 192.168.5.24411
12 D 192.168.5.8212
13 D 192.168.5.14313
```

Хочется, что то типа:

```
AA:BB:CC:DD:EE:FF android-a42cc69f72fe421a
AA:BB:CC:DD:EE:FF Galaxy-Tab-A-80-2019
AA:BB:CC:DD:EE:FF Redmi4-Redmi1111
AA:BB:CC:DD:EE:FF RedmiNote8T-Redmi
```

Comment: попробуйте написать `mac, hostname = line.split()[1:3]`

Comment: @Danis неа `D192.168.5.230
D192.168.5.245
D192.168.5.229
D192.168.5.195
D192.168.5.221
D192.168.5.113`

Comment: извините попробуйте так `mac, hostname = line.split()[2:4]`

Comment: @Danis  mac, hostname = line.split()[3:5] заработало, спасибо